# Postgresql summing duplicate elements

Tags: postgresql

In the table can exsist 2 lines that give the same information only a single column value is different. Basically the data is duplicated because of this 1 column. Can I somehow sum otherelement in such a manner that it takes this duplication into account ?

To illustrate the idea of the problem
Example:

```
|id|type|val1|val2|
|1 | 2  | 1  |  1 |
|1 | 3  | 1  |  1 |
|1 | 2  | 2  |  2 |
|1 | 3  | 2  |  2 |
```

Expected result

```
|id|type|val1|val2|count|
|1 |2,3 | 3  | 3  |  2  |
```

Actual result

```
|id|type|val1|val2|count|
|1 |2,3 | 6  | 6  |  4  |
```

In the actual data the type and val come from 2 different tables connected by 3rd table, so the query is like this:

```
SELECT id,
    array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT x.type ORDER BY x.type), ','::text) AS type,
    sum(y.val1) AS val1,
    sum(y.val2) AS val2,
    count(y.val1) AS count
   FROM a
     JOIN x ON x.a_id = a.id AND x.active = true
     JOIN y ON y.a_id = a.id AND y.active = true
  GROUP BY a.id
```

SOLUTION

```
 SELECT id,
        array_to_string(array_agg(DISTINCT x.type ORDER BY x.type), ','::text) AS type,
        sum(distinct y.val1) AS val1,
        sum(distinct y.val2) AS val2,
        count(distinct y.val1) AS count
       FROM a
         JOIN x ON x.a_id = a.id AND x.active = true
         JOIN y ON y.a_id = a.id AND y.active = true
      GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: if use `DISTINCT` in `sum` and `count` functions, you don't get what you want ?

Comment: Seems to be working ty.